# C code keeps running forever*

Tags: c, long-integer

I am trying to find the largest prime factor of a huge number in C ,for small numbers like 100 or even 10000 it works fine but fails (By fail i mean it keeps **running and running** for tens of minutes on my core2duo and i5) for very big `target` numbers (See code for the target number.)
Is my algorithm correct?

I am new to C and really struggling with big numbers. What i want is correction or guidance not a solution i can do this using python with bignum bindings and stuff (*I have not tried yet but am pretty sure*) but not in C. Or i might have done some tiny mistake that i am too tired to realize , anyways here is the code i wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// To find largest prime factor of target
int is_prime(unsigned long long int num);

long int main(void) {
    unsigned long long int target = 600851475143;
    unsigned long long int current_factor = 1;
    register unsigned long long int i = 2;
    while (i < target) {
        if ( (target % i) == 0  && is_prime(i) && (i > current_factor) ) { //verify i as a prime factor and greater than last factor
            current_factor = i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("The greates is: %llu \n",current_factor);
return(0);
}


int is_prime (unsigned long long int num) { //if num is prime 1 else 0 
    unsigned long long int z = 2;
    while (num > z && z !=num) {
        if ((num % z) == 0) {return 0;}
        z++;
    }

return 1;
}
```

Comment: ever stoped in a debugger to see where it is currently?
i would assume just from reading code without context, is_prime the loop might hang due to overflow

Comment: No i didn't , but i added some printf's to know if the code going on and it's working alright. But for how long?

Comment: Optimize `is_prime` to half: test for even, then set `z= 3` and increment with 2 every iteration of the loop.

Comment: It will take approximately one and a half hour....check it. 1 hr 45 min etc

Comment: 600 billion iterations will take some non-trivial amount of time.

Comment: It's from https://projecteuler.net/problem=3

Comment: So , i must wait that long? Or is there any better solution to this? Like make the code GPU based or something?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - If I'm reading the code correctly, `is_prime` should only be called a handful of times.

Comment: Yes , it'll only be called if only a factor of target is found!

Comment: In general `10^8` `O(1)` loop iterations take approximately 1 sec. Even if we consider `isprime` is `O(1)` which it isn't, the time taken will be ( `6x10^11/10^8`)atleast `6000` sec which is approximately an 1 hr 40 min.

Comment: @coderredoc - Where does 10^8 come from?

Comment: Shall , declare very variable to `register` to make it any faster? or is there any better algorithm to optimize prime declaration ?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth.: Well earlier when I used to do some competitive coding I heard thumb rule many times...(maybe SPOJ server specs etc)..and it worked. Strange enough.

Comment: Hint: What is the largest possible factor of some arbitrary value `x`?

Comment: x itself , i don't get the hint very well!

Comment: @UbdusSamad: True.  I guess I meant, factors others than `x` itself ;)

Comment: @UbdusSamad The `register` storage class has been mostly meaningless for at least a couple of decades. Some compilers simply ignore it, others only make it an error to take the variable's address.

Comment: Read wikipage on [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number). Think. Recode your stuff from start. Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger `gdb`**. BTW, you don't use bignums. See [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) wikipage. If you need bignums, use a library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: @UbdusSamad Also see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

600 billion iterations of anything will take some non-trivial amount of time.  You need to substantially reduce this.

Here's a hint:  Given an arbitrary integer value `x`, if we discover that `y` is a factor, then we've implicitly discovered that `x / y` is also a factor.  In other words, factors always come in pairs.  So there's a limit to how far we need to iterate before we're doing redundant work.

What is that limit?  Well, what's the crossover point where `y` will be greater than `x / y`?

Once you've applied this optimisation to the outer loop, you'll find that your code's runtime will be limited by the `is_prime` function.  But of course, you may apply a similar technique to that too.

Comment: If you are sure that the solution you are giving me hint of is correct then maybe  i should leave SE and go figure it myself , So are you very sure?

Comment: @UbdusSamad - Yes.  The bit I've "left as an exercise for the reader" is to figure out what that limit is :)

Comment: Okay , Thanks i'll work on it ,and also try running my first approach for 2 hours as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Please post it under hint , i won't look at it , i'll try doing it myself first but in bad cases atleast the answer will be there!

Comment: I got it! I think i understand what you were hinting , i'll optimize my code that way and hope for the best!

Answer (score 4):

By iterating until the square root of the number, we can get all of it's factors.( `factor` and `N/factor` and `factor<=sqrt(N)`). Under this small idea the solution exists. Any factor less than the `sqrt(N)` we check, will have corresponding factor larger than `sqrt(N)`. So we only need to check up to the `sqrt(N)`, and then we can get the remaining factors.

Here you don't need to use explicitly any prime finding algorithm. The factorization logic itself will deduce whether the target is prime or not. So all that is left is to check the pairwise factors.

```
unsigned long long ans ;
for(unsigned long long i = 2; i<=target/i; i++)
   while(target % i == 0){ 
      ans = i; 
      target/=i;
   }

if( target > 1 ) ans = target; // that means target is a prime.
//print ans
```

<sup>Edit: A point to be added (**chux**)- `i*i` in the earlier code  is may lead to overflow which can be avoided if we use `i<=target/i`.</sup>

<sup>Also another choice would be to have</sup>

```
unsigned long long sqaure_root = isqrt(target);
for(unsigned long long i = 2; i<=square_root; i++){
 ...
}
```

Here note than use of `sqrt` is not a wise choice since - 
*mixing of double math with an integer operation is prone to round-off errors.*

For target given the answer will be `6857`.

Comment: Note: `i*i` is subject to overflow.  `for(unsigned long long i = 2; i<=target/i; i++)` will not.  The cost of `target/i` is often minimal with good compiles that see `target % i` and compute `target % i` and `target/i` together.

Comment: @chux.: I guess `i <= sqrt(target)` or `i<=target/i` will be a better choice?

Comment: `sqrt(target)` is a poor choice. The mixing of `double` math with an integer operation is prone to round-off errors.  Recomputing `sqrt(target)` each loop is also weak.  Code could perform a prior `unsigned long long sqtarget = isqrt(target);` prior to the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Code has 2 major problems

1. The `while (i < target)` loop is very inefficient. Upon finding a factor, `target` could be reduced to `target = target / i;`.  Further, a factor `i` could occur multiple times.  Fix not shown.
2. `is_prime(n)` is very inefficient.  Its `while (num > z && z !=num)`  could loop `n` time.  Here too, use the quotient to limit the iterations to `sqrt(n)` times.

   ```
   int is_prime (unsigned long long int num) {
     unsigned long long int z = 2;
     while (z <= num/z) {
       if ((num % z) == 0) return 0;
       z++;
     }
     return num > 1;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`is_prime` has a chicken-and-egg problem in that you need to test `num` only against other primes. So you don't need to check against 9 because that is a multiple of 3.

`is_prime` could maintain an array of primes and each time a new `num` is tested that is a pime, it can be added to the array. `num` isr tested against each prime in the array and if it is not divisable by any of the primes in the array, it is itself a prime and is added to the array. The aray needs to be malloc'd and relloc'd unless there is a formue to calculate the number of primes up intil your target (I believe such formula does not exist).

EDIT: the number of primes to test for the target 600,851,475,143 will be approximately 7,500,000,000 and the table could run out of memory.

The approach can be adapted as follows:

- to use `unsiged int` up until primes of `UINT_max`
- to use `unsigned long long int` for primes above that
- to use brute force above a certain memory consumption.

`UINT_MAX` is defined as 4,294,967,295 and would cover the primes up to around 100,000,000,000 and would cost 7.5*4= 30Gb

See also [The Prime Pages](https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html).

Comment: ...downvotes without stating a reason should be prohibited... Can't see anything wrong with the approach. Please explain.

Comment: That array will eat memory , too much memory!

Comment: Optimising `is_prime` is unnecessary, as it's only called a handful of times.  Or rather, there's no point optimising it until the outer loop has been optimised.

Comment: @UbdusSamad, The number of primes is substantially less than the target.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong, it just needs optimization, for example:

```
int    is_prime(unsigned long long int num) { 
    if (num == 2) {
        return (1);                /* Special case */
    }
    if (num % 2 == 0 || num <= 1) {
         return (0);
    }
    unsigned long long int z = 3;  /* We skipped the all even numbers */
    while (z < num) {              /* Do a single test instead of your redundant ones */
        if ((num % z) == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        z += 2;                     /* Here we go twice as fast */
    }
return 1;
}
```

Also the big other problem is while (z < num) but since you don't want the solution i let you find how to optimize that, similarly look out by yourself the first function.

EDIT: Someone else posted 50 seconds before me the array-list of primes solution which is the best but i chose to give an easy solution since you are just a beginner and manipulating arrays may not be easy at first (need to learn pointers and stuff).

Comment: Thanks for downvotes... i suppose it's because of the not-optimal solution but keep in ming the OP said he is _learning_ C and this is easily understandable.

Comment: Oh all-right then, you should add the primes you find while looking to a dynamically allocated array of long long ints, i don't know how much RAM you got but it could lead to some problems with a low-end laptop for example... (actually it depends of your system's sizeof(long long int), i think on a small PC it should be just 8 not 16 so no real problem)

Comment: @ft_error, it depends on the addressing size of the machine (64 bit ints can be simulated while the machine is 32 bits).

Comment: I've got a Dell Lattitude e6400 core2duo and 4 gigs of ram and a lenovo with i5 and 8 gigs of ram! both of them on 64 bit architechture!